# ROS package not found after catkin_make

Tags: package, workspace, ros

I created a ROS workspace following the Wiki page from ROS. I also created a package using `catkin_create_pkg` under the workspace I just created.

Then, following the steps in ROS Wiki to build the package using `catkin_make`, after the package is built, I insert the command `rospack find packagename`, and my package is not found anymore.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you followed [this basic tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment)? You have to create the package in your workspace and have set properly your Bash file (in your home directory).

To permanently set your system, add these lines

```
# ROS settings
source <your_workspace_path>/catkin/devel/setup.bash
```

at the end of your `~/.bashrc`. Then, restart the terminal, and retry. Please, be sure to modify these lines with your actual information, where I've put `<your_workspace_path>` (depends on where you have installed ROS and its workspace on your PC).

If this does not solve the problem, try `rospack profile` before `rospack find <your_package_name>`.