# uwsim: package not found

Tags: ubuntu, ros

I installed ros kinetic and uwsim in my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

As the tutorials in wiki, I run `roscore` in a terminal, and run `rosrun uwsim uwsim` in another terminal to run UWSim.
The first time I run it just after installation finished, everything is okay.

However, when I closed the window and run it again, 
it returned `uwsim: package not found`.

Are there any necessary steps I left out? Or any other possible questions?

Great appreciation if anyone can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ros package not found after catkin\_make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053334/ros-package-not-found-after-catkin-make)

Comment: Did you build your catkin work space? I have some problems installing uwsim on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS as well.
I tried to dowload an updated version from [Oregon state university mirror](http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros-shadow-fixed/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-uwsim/) and to compile it with catkin_make but I get errors, some of them related to libxml++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit old but I just had the same issue.
In the second terminal where you run `rosrun uwsim uwsim`, you need to source the uwsim setup.bash file. 
It should be located at: `yourworkspace/devel_isolated/uwsim/setup.bash`

`source /.../yourworkspace/devel_isolated/uwsim/setup.bash`

If you want to avoid typing this all the time you can add the line to your `~/.bashrc` file.